# groovy script having access to domain classes

Tags: grails

I would like to have a groovy script that can access my domain classes and extract all properties from there.

I have not written any groovy-scripts so far within my Grails application.

How do I do this?

I am thinking of something like

```
run-script <scriptname>
```

In the script I would like to

```
For all Domain classes
  For all Fields
      println (<database-table-name>.<database-field-name>)
```

What would be the easiest approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Below I'm including a script code using which you can list down all the domain classes with their properties. This script generates a Map that contains the db mapping for domain and its properties. If you have a different requirement, you can achieve that using the same approach.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DomainClassArtefactHandler
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.persister.entity.GroovyAwareSingleTableEntityPersister as GASTEP
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory

//Include script dependencies required for task dependencies
includeTargets << grailsScript("Bootstrap")

target(grailsDomianMappings: "List down  field details for all grails domain classes") {
    //Task dependencies required for initialization of app. eg: initialization of sessionFactory bean
    depends(compile, bootstrap)

    System.out.println("Running script...")

    //Fetch session factory from application context
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = appCtx.getBean("sessionFactory")
    //Fetch all domain classes
    def domains = grailsApp.getArtefacts(DomainClassArtefactHandler.TYPE)

    GASTEP persister
    List<String> propertyMappings = []
    Map<String, List<String>> mappings = [:]

    //Iterate over domain classes
    for (DefaultGrailsDomainClass domainClass in domains) {
        //Get class meta data
        persister = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(domainClass.clazz) as GASTEP

        propertyMappings = []
        //fetch table name mapping
        String mappedTable = persister.tableName

        //fetch all properties for domain
        String[] propertyNames = persister.propertyNames
        propertyNames += persister.identifierPropertyName

        //fetch column name mappings for properties
        propertyNames.each {
            propertyMappings += persister.getPropertyColumnNames(it).first()
        }

        mappings.put(mappedTable, propertyMappings)
    }

    //Print data
    mappings.each { String table, List<String> properties ->
        properties.each { String property ->
            System.out.println("${table}.${property}")
        }
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    }
}
setDefaultTarget(grailsDomianMappings)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks awesome. I will try ASAP.

Comment: I have placed the above skript under scripts/domain.groovy. I try to run it with
    run script --stacktrace scripts/domain.groovy
I am getting the following error:

Loading Grails 2.3.5
.
|Environment set to development
...............................................................................................Error |
Error loading plugin manager: TomcatGrailsPlugin (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
...
.Error 
|
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
Error |
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

What can I do to work around?

Comment: run with --stacktrace and try to find the cause or add a new question with the updated stacktrace